# Scripting Openoffice in Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, scripting, csv, openoffice.org

I need to do some automation work on openoffice in Linux (desirably in Ruby):

1. Update some values
2. Open spreadsheet and recalculate
3. Save to csv

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [roo](http://rubygems.org/gems/roo). You can find some examples of what you need [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/roo/1.10.1/frames) and [here](http://roo.rubyforge.org/).

```
oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods")

[do stuff]

oo.to_csv
```